# Language convertion script

Tags: php, internationalization

I am doing a site with php.
I want to convert my English content to 7 other languages
( Chinese, Spanish, Malayalam, Telgu, Tamil, Kannada and Hindi).

Is there any script or anything like that to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately automatic translation of natural languages is very difficult since some things don't really translate directly.
You should look up gettext() if you want a mechanism for displaying different strings depending on the language.

Comment: Please DON'T EVER THINK ABOUT TRANSLATING ANYTHING USING AUTOMATED TRANSLATION SOFTWARE unless it's just for your personal needs. Better only provide english than adding a translation which wasn't done by someone who NATIVELY speaks the language AND is familiar with whatever your program does.

Comment: Please clarify whether you are looking for automatic translation, or just basic internationalization functions

Comment: internationalization functions

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html). Note this doesnt actually write the translations for you, you have to do that yourself or find someone to do that. Its simply a library to ease accessing/using the translations for static text strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" language="JavaScript1.2" src="http://uk.babelfish.yahoo.com/free_trans_service/babelfish2.js?from_lang=en&region=us"></script>
```

This javascript code links to the yahoo translation kit, then your page would be pulled in for translation into your reader's required choice.

But my suggestion would be for you to have all those pages pre-done by yourself and put into the database, and when a user requests for a specific language, you can query the page in preferred language.

These conversion kits might not give you a 100% correct translation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on http://php.net/manual/de/book.gettext.php or use a template engine - depends on your requirements, your skills and the effort you want to put into this work.

For starters http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html might give you an idea of how to do it.